# RPM package signing mandatory?

Tags: linux, rpm

Is it mandatory to sign a RPM? Will not signing the RPM cause any issues in terms of distribution or uploads to a central repository?

Comment: Define "central repository". But no, signing isn't necessary unless you want to be able to validate that the packages are what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 1):

Signing a package is not mandatory, but it is recommended for integrity verification reasons. If you are developing a package to be included in a large existing repository (e.g. EPEL, RPM Fusion, etc.) then they will sign the package with their key when they publish it.

Comment: They will likely also handle doing the actual building from source for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Recent (for several years) yum configurations require RPMs to be signed, by default.  You can of course *override* the default (disable GPG checking) with the [`--nogpgcheck`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html) option as noted in the [Fedora forum](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/31116/how-do-i-install-unsigned-packages-using-yum/).  So it is not *technically* mandatory, but management policies, e.g., customers of Red Hat may forbid the workaround.  Red Hat gives support to that in their [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Updating_Packages-Verifying_Signed_Packages.html).

In practice, you can sign any package using your own gpg signature (as detailed in [Thomas Chung's blog](http://fedoranews.org/tchung/gpg/)), and using `rpm --addsign`.  Yum will accept that just as well as any other signature.

Beyond the initial installation, the signature is of interest when verifying a package (checking for changes since it was installed, using `rpm -V`).  Whether a difference is found, if `rpm -qi` shows an unexpected (or missing) signature, that would demonstrate possible tampering with the package.

If you are installing for yourself alone, these matters are perhaps not very interesting.